# Ping and remote commands not working between two windows computers

Tags: dos, ping

I have two computers. One is a old windows vista named orla-pc and the other is a new windows 7 named homelaptop-hp
 If i run command prompt on orla-pc and type 
    `ping homelaptop-hp`

The ping sends out four packets, but does not receive any from homelaptop-hp. 
 The same thing happens when pinging from homelaptop-hp to orla-pc, it sends packets but doesn't receive them. I tried the command `tracert` (to trace my ping's route)
 and the result is:
 `* * * Request timed out`

 What should i do to get remote commands working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that the pc has the IP 10.0.0.4?
do you have a DHCP Server running? 
are both in the same subnet mask?

try to look with the cmd command "arp -a" if the pc has a entry in the ARP-Table

Maybe your router or a firewall blocks ICMP packets?
can you ping your router?

greetings

Comment: Ok, i CAN ping the router sucessfully with 100% packet response. The computer i am currently running is included in the ARP Table, now what? What settings should be on my firewall?

Comment: But i cant ping other computers on my network, please help

Comment: hmm, i have only the German version here, but you can try to add a rule in both win firewalls.
you have to open your Firewall (start + typing "firewall") and add a new incoming rule. there you choose "custom (?)" rule and ICMPv4. Then you click "customize (?)" and check the Echorequest button. 

i uploaded a picture that makes it hopefully clearer.
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3171/83bi7gwr_png.htm

sorry, i only have a german version -.-

Comment: i tried that earlier... no luck

Comment: what are the IPs from your pc / router? which subnet mask do you use? do you use DHCP or static IPs?

Comment: the ip of orla-pc is 10.0.0.9 homlaptop-hp is 10.0.0.4 and router is 10.0.0.1 how do i find the DHCPar static ips?

Comment: Hansinger? Are you still active in this solution?

Comment: I do not know what it could be. In my case it was located on the firewall setting. Sorry

Comment: thats ok, i will accept that answer anyways